# Is setting value of the localStorage a side effect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, redux

I'm working on a React+Redux app that must save *certain* values from the store to `localStorage`. I have some utility function, that securely store values to `localStorage`. I have an action (thunk) and reducer.

```
const wallet = (state = getFromLocalStorage('wallet'), action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET_WALLET':
      setToLocalStorage('wallet', action.payload); // <--- **SIDE EFFECT?**
      retrun action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Reducers must be pure functions. Does the `getToLocalStorage` function call break the purity of the reducer? And if so, where is the proper place to call this function?

Comment: I'm confused. You asked about `getToLocalStorage` breaking the purity of the function, but surely it's the `setToLocalStorage` call that does that? (Whether that's a problem for a reducer isn't something I can help with, but that call to `setToLocalStorage` definitely means it's not a pure function.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other comment stated: yes, it's definitely a side effect.  Now, it's probably not going to *break* anything in this case, but a reducer isn't the right place for that.

A better solution would be to either do this in a store subscription callback or a middleware.  Or, even better, use one of the [many store persistence libraries already available](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/store-persistence.md).  Doing so in a thunk would also be an acceptable option, especially if you just want to persist a small amount of data rather than the entire store state.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely a side effect in FP terms, but actually there is nothing bad with your code. There is no other better workaround of sharing your state between components (or even outside react.js tree) except redux/flux maybe.

Functional programming is a good thing but you don't need to turn that into cult

Comment: Is calling `setToLocalStorage` in action is better aproach? because that action is thunk and is already impure and may contain some logic (like ajax request)