# Save to localStorage from reducer hook

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the useReducer hook to save some global state. Because I would like to save some settings when the browser is closed, I save those settings to local storage.

At the moment I use dispatch to save the setting and a separate function to save this to local storage, but it would be nice if the setting is automatically saved after dispatch. (sometimes I forget to save to local storage and have a difference between state/local storage)

Reading the state from local storage is not a problem. I use the initialState parameter in the useReducer hook for this.

I think the answer is to not do it, but what is the alternative? (without using redux)

Comment: This question is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50945152/is-setting-value-of-the-localstorage-a-side-effect

Answer (score 8):

**Edit**: inspired by this nice concise approach to [locally persisting a `useState` hook](https://dev.to/selbekk/persisting-your-react-state-in-9-lines-of-code-9go), this is a better approach to locally persisting a `useReducer` hook (untested, but should be roughly correct):

```js
import { useReducer, useEffect } from 'react'

function useLocallyPersistedReducer(reducer, defaultState, storageKey, init = null) {
  const hookVars = useReducer(reducer, defaultState, (defaultState) => {
    const persisted = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageKey))
    return persisted !== null
      ? persisted
      : init !== null ? init(defaultState) : defaultState
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(hookVars[0]))
  }, [storageKey, hookVars[0]])

  return hookVars
}
```

This gets rid of the need for the extra ref, and adds support for the [optional `init` function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initialization). More importantly, it also only updates local storage whenever the state is updated, rather than on every render.

---

I was just playing around with doing something similar, and wanted to try and achieve it using a custom hook that could be used in place of useReducer. Came up with the following rough hook (I did add an extra parameter so I can specify the key the data gets stored under):

```js
// DO NOT USE THIS; see the updated implementation above instead
import { useRef, useReducer } from 'react'

function useLocallyPersistedReducer(reducer, defaultState, storageKey) {
  const isLoading = useRef(true)
  if (isLoading.current) {
    try {
      const persisted = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageKey))
      defaultState = persisted
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn(`Failed to load state '${storageKey}' from localStorage; using default state instead`)
    }
    isLoading.current = false
  }

  const [ state, dispatch ] = useReducer(reducer, defaultState)

  try {
    localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(state))
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(`Failed to store updated state '${storageKey}'`)
  }

  return [ state, dispatch ]
}
```

As a rough job, it works, but there are probably some nuances that I've missed. Hope that gives you an idea of how you could approach it though!

Comment: Interesting. Would like to see this get constructively critiqued, could be a useful pattern to adopt.

Comment: Question, why is there a need to use useRef in this case? (just curious)

Comment: The reason that I included this in the first place was because we want a way to ensure the state is loaded the first time the hook is run. Without that, it would run each time the component re-renders.

Comment: @OamarKanji: actually, turns out you don't need the ref; see the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I found the @Zaid Crouch a great one but it doesn't handle local storage updates coming from different windows (tabs/iframe/popup).

```
import { useReducer, useEffect, Dispatch } from 'react'

// Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346866/save-to-localstorage-from-reducer-hook
export type ReducerType<T> = (state: T, action: ActionType) => (T)
export type InitType<T> = (state: T) => void
export interface ActionType {
    type: string
}

var dispatcher:Dispatch<ActionType> | null = null

const LOCAL_STORAGE_UPDATED_IN_A_DIFFERENT_WINDOW = "LOCAL_STORAGE_UPDATED_IN_A_DIFFERENT_WINDOW"
export function useLocallyPersistedReducer<T>
    (reducer: ReducerType<T>, defaultState: T, storageKey: string, init?:InitType<T>) : [T, Dispatch<ActionType>] {

    const reducerWrapper = (status: T, action: ActionType) => {
        switch (action.type){
            case LOCAL_STORAGE_UPDATED_IN_A_DIFFERENT_WINDOW:
                const statusReadFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageKey) || "{}")
                return statusReadFromLocalStorage
            default: return reducer(status, action)
        }
    }

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducerWrapper, defaultState, (defaultState) => {
        const persisted = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageKey) as string)
        return persisted !== null
            ? persisted
            : init ? init(defaultState) : defaultState
    })

    // NOTE Even if this codes runs multiple time we add only one event listener as long as the callback is singleton
    dispatcher = dispatch
    window.addEventListener('storage', listenForStorageChangesInOtherWindows, {once: true});

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(state))
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [localStorage, storageKey, state])

    return [state, dispatch]
}

const listenForStorageChangesInOtherWindows = (key: any) => {
    dispatcher && dispatcher({type: LOCAL_STORAGE_UPDATED_IN_A_DIFFERENT_WINDOW})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's wise to make a service responsible for storing your data from and to localStorage. So you may want to create a service with a get and a set function. You can call the service from an effect in redux.

In my opinion, the reducer is there to change the state.

You can also use rxjs to wait for the reducer to update your state, and then grab that and save it to localStorage using your service.

By the way, depening on you needs I don't really see any reason why you should not store data in localStorage as long as (when using redux) you keep in mind that you redux state is your single and only truth. Storing data somewhere to restore that state on initialization is a good approach in my hounest opinion.

Here is an example using ngrx :

```
@Effect()
myAction$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<MyAction>(actions.myAction),
  debounceTime(300),
  switchMap((action) =>
    this.service.post(action.dto).pipe(
      map((response: SomeDto) => {
        // This updates the state using a reducer
        return new CreateShortenedLinkSuccess(response);
      }),
      tap((value) => {
        // Here, you can use the value param, to save
        // changes to localStorage
        this.router.navigate([`/mgmt/link/${value.dto.id}`]);
      }),
      catchError((response: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        // Do scary stuff
      })
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: I have a service (get/set), but when to call it without redux? I like to keep the states in sync to avoid confusion/user problems.

Comment: You can add a value in your state, for example initializedYn. If it's false, you use the values from localStorage to produce an initial state and then set initializedYn to true. Once that's done, your redux store is ALWAYS the truth. In that case you just store changes in the store to localStorage but NEVER the other way around.

Comment: The initial state is not a problem because useReducer has an extra parameter for this. "In that case you just store changes in the store to localStorage but NEVER the other way around." -> but how?

Comment: Then just use an effect, perform some action, change the state and use the effect to save the changed state to localStorage.
I'll update the answer with an example from ngrx

Comment: Sorry, but the question is about React. (see tag)